# Kotlin's data class, Android Room and custom setter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I got an entity for Android Room which looks like that. So far, no worries.

```
@Entity(tableName = "users",
        indices = arrayOf(Index(value = "nickName", unique = true)))
data class User(@ColumnInfo(name = "nickName") var nickName: String,
                @ColumnInfo(name = "password") var password: String) {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

Now I need to encrypt the password. With Java, this would simply be done with a setter and that would work.

How would you do that with Kotlin. I cannot find a solution to combine Android Room, custom setters and data classes.

Comment: Why cant you override the setter of the value?

Comment: Your question is unclear. "With Java, this would simply be done with a setter and that would work." - and what's wrong with Kotlin's mutable properties?

Comment: @Egor how do you do that for a data class? Via a private `_password` field? In that case, where do your wire the @ColumnInfo?

Comment: @VincentMimoun-Prat I guess it's not a proper way to encode a password inside setter method from design perspective, just encode it outside and pass then to the model

Comment: You may be interested to know that best practice is to not store the password but to store a salt and hashing of the password. e.g. See http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html.

Comment: @mfulton26 Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @ledniov Since my question, that is what I am doing now. But I would still be interested in the answer though for other use cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users",
        indices = arrayOf(Index(value = "nickName", unique = true)))
data class User(@ColumnInfo(name = "nickName") var nickName: String,
                private var _password: String) {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "password")
    var password: String = _password
        set(value) {
            field = "encrypted"
        }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "User(id=$id, nickName='$nickName', password='$password')"
    }

}
```

But I wouldn't recommend encrypting password inside Entity or modifying it somehow as it isn't its responsibility and you may face errors with double encryption of your password as when you retrieve your entity from database Room will populate the entity with data which will lead to encryption of already encrypted data.

Comment: This'll solve the problem but now there must be two columns in the table, '_password' and 'password'. I also tried annotating '_password' with @Ignore, but ROOM wouldn't compile. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DariushMalek, as I wrote in the answer - I wouldn't recommend such approach, it's better to do any operations over data ourside of data class, use it only as a container for getting and setting the data.

Answer (score -5):

```
    @Entity(tableName = "users",
            indices = arrayOf(Index(value = "nickName", unique = true)))
    data class User(@ColumnInfo(name = "nickName") var nickName: String,
                    @ColumnInfo(name = "password") var password: String) {
    var _password = password
        set(value): String{
           //encrypt password
        }
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Long = 0
    }
```

This will create a custom setter so every time you set your password you can encrypt it as well inside the setter.

Comment: Is not even compiling

Comment: Results in an IDE compilation error: "overload resolution ambiguous"

Comment: Getters and setters can be called custom within a data class but you have to create a new variable for it. So variable "password" would need to be called something else. For example _password